# Check to see if an ID exists in a database

Tags: mysql, exists

When given an `ID` number, I want to check to see if it exists in the database. Return `true` if the `ID` is found and if not, then return `false`.

My knowledge of MySQL is very low, but I am assuming it would be something to do with the `COUNT(*)` function possibly?

Answer (score 23):

```
select id from table where id = $id
```

No need to get fancy. Using exists with subqueries seems likely only to generate poor performance, but I'm happy to be corrected if shown otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add another example.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 'number'; 
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 'number'; 1 - exists,
```

In your PHP or other code, you must check if one of these queries return value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the solution where you select the id because it requires a null check in your application code. Rather, I prefer to select a dummy table and use a left join so that a result is always returned:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS record_found
FROM
    ( SELECT 0 ) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN
    table1 AS t1
    ON
    t1.id = $id
```